# Помогите понять что за функцию сдвига надо сделать и для чего? бинарный сдвиг на n разрядов

Tags: битовые-операции, c, c++

```
При написании функций можно использовать только следующее:
- целочисленные константы;
- целочисленные аргументы функций и автоматические (локальные)переменные;
- операции   ~ !     +  -   (тип)   <<  >>   &    ^     |    . Группы операций расположены в порядке   убывания приоритета.
```

> ```
> int MoveRight(int x, int n, int onebit);
> MoveRight - сдвигает х вправо на n разрядов с заполнением значением
> ```
>
> onebit (только 0 или 1) освободившихся
> разрядов
>     Примеры: MoveRight(0x123,4,1) = 0xF012
>             MoveRight(0x123,4,0) = 0x12

***Спасибо большое***

Comment: @Анатолийй если вы не понимаете задание, то лучше всего спросить о нем у того, кто вам его дал - вряд ли препод хотел, чтобы вы гадали, что же ему от вас нужно.

Comment: Сдвиг на n разрядов вправо, заполнив освободившиеся разряды 1 или 0. Пример:
Исходное число:

    0000 0001 0010 0011 (0x123)

Сдвигаем вправо на 4 разряда заполняя 0:

    0000 0000 001 0010 (0x12)

Сдвигаем вправо на 4 разряда заполняя 1:

    1111 0000 001 0010 (0xF012)

Comment: @Анатолийй, у вас тип int двухбайтовый (short), как в приведенном примере? Или на самом деле 4-байтовый, как в большинстве реализаций, но функция оперирует только двумя младшими байтами, а старшие равны 0? Или пример такой только для краткости? От этого очень сильно зависит реализация функции. Определитесь, что вам нужно сделать.

Comment: Представьте аргумент unsigned. Сдвигаете вправо -- нулями заполнится автоматически.

Если надо заполнять единичками, то делаете маску с единичками в `n` старших разрядах и после сдвига накладываете ее на результат (через ИЛИ).

А разрядность аргумента определите через sizeof. Соответственно в битах получится `sizeof(x) \* CHAR_BIT` (из limits.h).

Просто не забывайте, что знаковый разряд -- самый старший. При сдвиге signed вправо он распространяется. Так что, можете просто поиграться приведением типов.

Вот, собственно, и вся "теория". (Расшифровку незнакомых слов можно погуглить).

Comment: Вот здесь [Bit Twiddling Hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) очень много всего разного о битиках.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int MoveRight(int x, int n, int bit)
{
    return (unsigned int)x >> n | bit << (sizeof(int)*8-1) >> (n - 1);
}

int main()
{

    cout << hex << MoveRight(0x123, 1, 1) << " " << MoveRight(0x123, 4, 0);
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: По-моему `bit << (sizeof(int)*8-1)` при `bit ==1` дает undefined behavior, т.к. `1 * 2^(sizeof(int)*8-1)` не представимо в виде `int`.